# auto-pst-pdf creates ghostscript error

Tags: eps, psfrag, ghostscript, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

I am using `pdflatex` (shell-escape is enabled) with `auto-pst-pdf`, `psfrag` and `chemnum` to replace tags in eps-files for auto-numbering molecules in my B.Sc. thesis. It went fine until this week, when I got the errors:

`GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error` and

The error does not occur without the `auto-pst-pdf` package but I haven't found alternatives for my intention.

I tested a MWE and there is no error with an eps-file. With an png-file I get a ghostscript-error:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}              

\usepackage{        
    caption,        
    graphicx,  
    libertine,
    lmodern
}

\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off,cleanup=]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\begin{document}
plain text
\begin{figure}

   \includegraphics{test.png}

\end{figure}
plain text with \cmpd{1}
\end{document}
```

However if I reduce my "original" thesis.tex to the packages above and even if I don't include no eps-files (even if I only have my titlepage) I get the errors named above. I also tried to save my document in another directories but it didn't change anything. How can this be?
Can it be a dvi2ps or ps2pdf error?

Update: There was a `pst-pdf`-Update, but it didn't fix my error. However I managed to copy an error log directly from Texstudio. It seems to abort creating the pdf-graphics after some time (not always after the same image).

Error-log when I use both png- and eps-graphics

```
This is dvips(k) 2020.1 Copyright 2020 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) ' TeX output 2020.10.12:1150' -> main-autopp.ps dvips: Font Helvetica used in file pics/Chatt-Disprop.eps is not in the mapping file. [...] dvips: Font Helvetica used in file pics/PNP-TMS/PNP-TMS_Ligand.eps is not in the mapping file. dvips: Font Helvetica-Bold used in file pics/PNP-TMS/PNP-TMS_Ligand.eps is not in the mapping file. <c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro> <c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro> <c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro>

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/psfrag/psfrag.pro>

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/libertine/lbtn_76gpa5.enc>

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/libertine/lbtn_25tcsq.enc>

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/dvips/base/color.pro>

.

<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTB.pfb> <c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/libertine/LinLibertineT.pfb> [1

<./pics/Chatt-Zyklus.eps>

] [2

<./pics/Chatt-Disprop.eps>

[...]
<./pics/PNP-Cy/PNP-Cy_Ligand.eps>

] [22

<./pics/PNP-Cy/Komplex.eps>

] [23

<./pics/PNP-TMS/PNP-TMS_Ligand.eps>

]



GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

system returned with code 1 system returned with code 1

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

Comment: The comment conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116993/discussion-on-question-by-chris-auto-pst-pdf-creates-ghostscript-error), so it may continue there or just be archived.